# JS: Do I override or add in fields when use _.extend() in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I have an object and I put it as an extension of another object in which I put value for some of the extended fields - is it going to be rewritten or the value will be added to the old one?

For example if I have:

```
const PATCH_REQUEST_SCHEMA = {
    'type': 'object',
    'title': 'Some object',
    'description': 'Some object Representation',
    'properties': {
        'name': {
            'type': 'string',
            'minLength': 1,
            'maxLength': 256,
            'title': 'Name'
        }
};

const POST_REQUEST_SCHEMA =  _.extend({}, PATCH_REQUEST_SCHEMA, {
    'properties': {
        'surname': {
            'type': 'string',
            'minLength': 1,
            'maxLength': 256,
            'title': 'Surname'
        }
    }
});
```

What would be the result for POST_REQUEST_SCHEMA.properties ?

Will it be:

```
{
    'name': {
        'type': 'string',
        'minLength': 1,
        'maxLength': 256,
        'title': 'Name'
    },
    'surname': {
        'type': 'string',
        'minLength': 1,
        'maxLength': 256,
        'title': 'Surname'
    }
}
```

or:

```
{
    'surname': {
        'type': 'string',
        'minLength': 1,
        'maxLength': 256,
        'title': 'Surname'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested it manually - it rewrites/overrides the field "properties". So the answer is:

```
{
  'surname': {
    'type': 'string',
    'minLength': 1,
    'maxLength': 256,
    'title': 'Surname'
  }
}
```